# Hadoop jobtracker's tracking url cannot access

Tags: hadoop, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have configured my hadoop system in wsl and run the wordcount example. But when I want to see the history of the job, I found the tracking url cannot access.

The job is working well, the jobhistory is running as well.

[image]

The history tracking url is my wsl hostname:8088/proxy/application_1585482453915_0002/.

[image]

You can see the url above.

But I can still access to localhost:19888/jobhistory to see my jobhistory.

[image]

How is this problem occurs? Is it a problem of configuration?

My hadoop version is 2.7.1.

My core-site.xml

```
<property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>file:/home/hadoop/hadoop/tmp</value>
        <description>Abase for other temporary directories.</description>
    </property>
    <property>
　　　　    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
　　　　    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
```

My hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/home/hadoop/hadoop/tmp/dfs/name</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:/home/hadoop/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data</value>
    </property>
```

My mapred-site.xml

```
<property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
        <value>localhost:10020</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>    
        <value>localhost:19888</value>
    </property>
```

My yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
      <value>false</value>
      <description>Whether virtual memory limits will be enforced for containers</description>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
      <value>4</value>
      <description>Ratio between virtual memory to physical memory when setting memory limits for containers</description>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
  </property>
```

My /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   DESKTOP-U1EOV4J.localdomain DESKTOP-U1EOV4J
```

Answer (score 0):

The `JobHistoryServer` daemon is running in `localhost` (127.0.0.1), whereas the tracking URL is constructed with the hostname, thus redirecting to `DESKTOP-U1EOV4J.localdomain` (127.0.1.1).

For a Pseudo distributed cluster, it is safer to leave the host of `JobHistoryServer` to be `0.0.0.0`.

Update the job history server properties in `mapred-site.xml`

```
   <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0:10020</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>    
        <value>0.0.0.0:19888</value>
    </property>
```

and restart the `JobHistoryServer`.